# Many-to-many and one-to-many relationships between two entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entities - **Student** and **Form**. A student can have many forms as well as one current form. Over the lifetime of a Student's education, more form classes will be added to the **Forms** collection.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }       
    public Form CurrentForm { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Form> Forms { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    [Key]
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

With the following Student configuration.

```
builder.HasOne(s => s.CurrentForm)
       .WithMany(f => f.Students)
       .IsRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(s => s.FormId);

builder.HasMany(s => s.Forms)
       .WithMany(f => f.Students);
```

The migration error that I then receive is as follows:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Form.Students' and 'Student.Forms' because a relationship already exists between 'Form.Students' and 'Student.CurrentForm'.

I understand why the error is saying this to a point, however I'm now unsure of how to mitigate this going forward. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: I would change this slightly, keep only the one-many relationship. Then either have a flag to show the form is active or use Effective from and Effective to dates on the Form itself. Having a new relationship just to define the Current Form is not practical. Form is one entity, the business rules of Active is what is differentiating it from the others - not the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @DawoodAwan. Students still require the need for many Forms. I did think that having a third class of StudentForm with the fields you stated was an option, effectively having a many-to-many relationship between Form and Student. I was just wondering if the question above is possible to represent a tighter business model.

Comment: Based on your initial statement " Student and Form. A student can have many forms as well as one current form." This means this is a one-many relationship, 1 Student Multiple forms. Not sure why you need a many-many relationship? If the form can be active/inactive then just add a flag or Effective From/To fields on the Form entity. Unless the same Form can be assigned to multiple students, in that case it would be different.